# maven profile can't get the property

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

Please tell me what could be the problem?

**The test crashes on an error:**
Failures: java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: url=null

**pom.xml:**

```
 <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.21.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <db.url>https://dev.site.com/</db.url>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

**BaseTest.java:**

```
@BeforeClass (alwaysRun = true)
public void setUp() {

    Logger.getLogger("com.dataart.demo.java.logging.SomeClass").log(Level.INFO,System.getProperty("db.url"));

     if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("win")) {
         driverPath = "src/test/resources/chromedriver86.exe";
     }
     else {
         driverPath = "src/test/resources/chromedriverlinux86";
     }
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
    LoggingPreferences logs = new LoggingPreferences();
    logs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.SEVERE);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    HashMap<String, Object> chromePref = new HashMap<>();
    chromePref.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
    chromePref.put("download.default_directory", System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePref);
    options.addArguments("headless");
    options.addArguments("window-size=1800,1000");
    options.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logs);
    options.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10L, SECONDS);
    driver.get(System.getProperty("db.url")); // line 71
}
```

Failures: java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: url=null

http://joxi.ru/D2PqDR9uJ8PBlA

Comment: Which of the those lines is line 71 mentioned in the output? How do you start the test? Btw. please add the Maven Output as text and not as a screenshot.

Comment: Passing system-properties via configuration in the failsafe-plugin **should** work: tested with **maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration should work if you start an individual test. (inside the IDE)

But the test will fail in you do `mvn install`, `mvn test`, ...

> Failures: java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry:
> url=null

Then you should also configure the `surefire-plugin`

```xml
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <db.url>https://dev.site.com/</db.url>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <db.url>https://dev.site.com/</db.url>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a maven perspective, I think you should look into this snippet below (this is derived from previous answer):

1. The surefire/failsafe configuration goes in to the `pluginManagement`. If you need to override systemProperty for one module, you may do so. If needed, you may also merge/replace parent configuration (see this Q/A: [Append or merge default maven plugin configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593994/append-or-merge-default-maven-plugin-configuration)).
2. The configuration for both will inject a system property `db.url` with value `${test.db.url}`
3. The value of said property is configured inside the profile.

This aims to avoid duplicating the surefire/failsafe configuration, especially if the `db.url` is not the single property you need to configure.

You could also read this from a filtered file, using maven resources plugin (and also avoid using global shared context, eg: `System.getProperty`). And I think that's personally the best (I prefer a configuration file over a system property, the former is easier to share).

```
<project>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId> <version>2.22.2</version> <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <db.url>${test.db.url}</db.url>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration> </plugin> 
        <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> <version>2.22.2</version> <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <db.url>${test.db.url}</db.url>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration> </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  <profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <activation> <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault> </activation>
    <properties>
      <test.db.url>https://dev.site.com/</test.db.url>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</project>
```